# Solve a system of two equations in three unknowns locking the param to integer number

Tags: systems-of-equations

I have a system as follows

$$6 + 4n = x,\quad
    8 + 3m = x.$$

now I know I can get to the point where:

$$n = (2 + 3m)/4,$$

and I can parametrize $m$ as $z$ to get all possible values in $R$.

What I want to do instead is to lock down $n$ and $m$ to be integer numbers instead of real numbers. And I'd like to get the very first number if that exist.

In the example above $m = 1$ wouldn't work since $n$ would be $1.25$. However $m = 2$ would do the trick and would lead to $n = 2$.

I wonder, how do I set in the system this constraint?

Edit: I guess one idea there could be to round up to the next integer by doing something like

$$m = 1,\quad
n = (2 + 3 * 1 + 4 - 1)/4.$$

Would that be correct?

Comment: Do you know about modular arithmetic?

Comment: not sure :) can you expand?

Comment: If $m$ is an integer, for $(2+3m)/4$ to be an integer you want $2+3m \equiv 0 \mod 4$, which is equivalent to $m \equiv 2 \mod 4$.

Comment: Hi, thanks.. wouldn't this be (2 + 3m) mod 4 = 0 ? Also how did you get from 1st to 2nd step?

Comment: $\mod 4$ is something that applies to the whole equation, not just one side of it:  $a \equiv b \mod c$ means $a-b$ is a multiple of $c$.

Comment: Starting from $2 + 3 m \equiv 0 \mod 4$, you subtract $2$ from both sides, then multiply by $3$ which is its own multiplicative inverse mod $4$.

Comment: so just to understand this step by step, I figured I've asked the same question to @poetasis below. Can you correct the following steps by steps (I think they are wrong)
$$2 + 3m = 0  mod 4$$
$$3m = -2  mod 4$$
$$m = -2/3  mod 4$$
what do i do now (I suppose there is a mistake from step 2 tbh :( )

Comment: I think I see what you've done there..correct me if I'm wrong:
once you have $3m = -2 (mod 4)$ then you multipy by 3 as you say and you would get $9m = -6$ but since the equation is locked to mod 4 then you do $9 mod 4 = 1$ and $-6 mod 4 = 2$ is that correct? I wasn't aware that you can just move down all the numbers in the equation to mod 4 independently like in this way..

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  8 + 3m = x\\
  6 + 4n = x\\
2+3m-4n=0\\
m=\dfrac{2(2n-1)}{3}\implies n=3k-1
\end{align*}

From this we can easily see when all three valiables are integers, i.e. when
$2n-1$ is a multiple of $3$.

$$m,n,x\in\mathbb{N}\quad\iff \quad
n\in\big\{2,5,8,\cdots ,(3k-1)\big\},
\space k\in\mathbb{N}
$$

Comment: thanks.. yes I can "visually" see "when all three valiables are integers" but I wonder what is the formula that for instance will lead to the first integer number in the sequence. In the example, when n = 2 for instance

Comment: @Andrea Giuliano The fist number is 
$n=3k-1=3(1)-1=2.\quad$ Then 
$m=\dfrac{2\big(2(n)-1\big)}{3}=\dfrac{2\big(2(2)-1\big)}{3}=\dfrac{2(3)}{3}=2.\quad $
 Then $x\quad=8 + 3m=8+3(2)=14\quad= 6+4n=6+4(2)=14.\qquad$  Just remember $k\in\{1,2,3,4,5,....\}$

Comment: thanks @poetasis. I was trying to do the same with another equation to check what I'm still missing here.. suppose we have 
$$1 + n = x\quad
5 + 2m = x$$

that leads us to
$$n = 4 + 2m$$
if we substitute m to k where $$k = 1, 2, 3, ...$$ that gives us $$n = 6.$$

However I was expecting n to be 5 since 1 + n for n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 is the series 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...
And 5 + 2m where m = 0, 1, 2, 3 is the series 5, 7, 9, .. so the first number they intersect is actually 5..
What am I missing here?

Comment: also,  Followup question: how did you infer that $$n = 3k -1$$ ?

Comment: @Andrea Giuliano only when $n=3k-1$ can $2n-1$ be a multiple of $3$. so $n\in\{2,5,8,11,\cdots.\quad$ This makes $\dfrac{2n-1}{3}\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\in\{2,4,6,8\cdots\}$ and you can figure out $x$.

Comment: thanks @poetasis! yeah I get how we get from $$n = 3k - 1$$ to the rest but I was wondering how do we go from:
$$(2n -1) mod 3 = 0$$ to $$n = 3k -1$$ ?

Comment: @Andrea Giuliano It is not $3k-1 mod 3=0\quad$ What we have is $\big(2(3k-1)-1\big)\equiv 0 \pmod 3$

Comment: ok, I'm sure I'm missing something :) sorry for being dumb but not sure how are we getting the $$n = 3k -1$$ from the initial equations?

Comment: @Andrea Giuliano   From the original equations we know 
$\quad m=\dfrac{2(2n-1)}{3}\quad $ and we can see that $\quad (2n-1)\quad$ must be a multiple of $3.\quad$
This means $\quad n=3k-1\quad$ and
$\quad m=\dfrac{2\big(2(3k-1)-1\big)}{3}$

Comment: thank you! so the part I'm struggling with is this: 

we can see that $$(2−1)$$ must be a multiple of 3. This means $$=3−1$$

How did we get from "expression must be multiple of 3" to $$=3−1$$?

Comment: @Andrea Giuliano
 How else do you get $2n-1$ being a multiple of $3?$ What numbers do you plug in for $n?$ Play with it on paper and you might see.

Comment: sorry I've tried but unsuccessfully... if you have to express $2n-1$ being a multiple of 3 in a math equation, and then derive to the $3k -1$ would you mind to show how would you do it step by step?

Comment: here's what I tried.. to impose 2n-1 is a multiple of 3 I can have the following equation:
$$2n - 1 = 3k   mod 3$$
form this I can go here
$$n = (3k + 1)/2   mod 3$$

from this point I get stuck and I don't really know how to go to 
$$n = 3k -1$$

Comment: @Andrea Giuliano
 Somehow you need to generate $n\in\big\{2,5,8,11,\cdots\big\}.\quad $ This happens with $n=3k-1$

Comment: alright, let me try in a different way... say you have the following
$$an + b$$ and you want to add in your system that such is divisible by c. How would you get n and k?

Comment: @Andrea Giuliano
   I am done with my attempts to help. Good luck